# Where should I store IDE component editor user preferences?

Tags: delphi, ide

I'm writing a component editor for the Delphi 10 Seattle IDE which has some form layout customization, such as re-sizing the form, positioning it, splitters to re-side panels, etc. I would like to save these settings so that each time the user opens this editor, it opens in the same layout they last left it.

I'm assuming the location to save such settings should reside somewhere within the `HKCU` section of the registry, along-side the specific Delphi IDE version settings.

Where in the registry should I save such settings?

Comment: why not hkcu/software/company/softwaretitle/usersettings  ?

Comment: @JohnEasley Because I'm pretty sure there must be some standard place where all the other editors also save their settings, and am assuming that I should keep mine there too.

Comment: The BDS registry should belong to the IDE, IMO. The proper thing to do is what John mentioned, in which case your *brand new question to investigate* disappears; if you properly store under your own registry key, you won't need to care which version of the IDE is running. CNWizards and GExperts both use their own registry keys.

Comment: @KenWhite Perhaps true, but I'd still want to separate it per version. Each IDE may already have its own layout and therefore the user may want this dialog to be in a certain location for a certain IDE.

Comment: In recent versions, you can check the RTLVersion constant in your code, as in `if RTLVersion = <somevalue> then` to detect which version of the RTL is in use, from which you can determine which version of the IDE it is that's running your code.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I was just researching exactly that.

Comment: @KenWhite GExperts actually doesn't. It stores its settings under HKCU\software\...\<delphiversion>\GEXperts-1.3 this has the advantage that it doesn't need to distinguish between Delphi versions within its own settings, because each Delphi version already has its own registry branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging further into the registry, I'm pretty sure I found it.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Property Editors\`

It appears that other property and component editors keep their properties here, for example the `TActionList`. There are traces of editors storing their dimensions in this node.

Comment: Which raises a brand new question for me to investigate: How to detect the version of Delphi so I can look in the appropriate location of the registry...

Comment: OTA provides registry root for current session.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Yes, there's `IOTAServices.GetBaseRegistryKey`. This will not only use the correct version of Delphi (the current one) but also the correct registry key which can be changed by starting the IDE with the -r [command line switch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options). (Feel free to post this as the answer, IMHO it's the right one.)